# Can anyone tell where it is possible to check status and validity of an official design patent?

Tags: design-patent

In reference to the patent: [USD513897](https://www.google.com/patents/USD513897)

Answer (score 2):

The best site to check a US patent's status is the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). Pair is extremely picky with respect to specifying the document to be searched. In this case, get past the CAPTCHA and then select "Patent Number" and enter "D513897" in the search box. If you do this you can see that the status is "Patented Case" which means the patent was granted. You can check the fee status and you'll get the message that for design patents, no fees are due. According to the [USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1505.html), the term for design patents is:

> U.S. design patents resulting from applications filed on or after May
>   13, 2015 have a 15 year term from the date of grant. However, patents
>   issued from design applications filed before May 13, 2015 have a 14
>   year term from the date of grant.

The grant date for this design patent is January, 31 2006 and it should expire 14 years from that date.

Comment: Looking it up in PAIR will not give you an answer to the validity part of your question.

Comment: Interesting comment. Are there many instances of issued design patents which have been later deemed invalid?